# The Value stored inside while(read()) loop is unable to retrieve the value outside while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop, ado.net

How do do you retrieve the data after a while loop?

```
con220.Open();
SqlDataReader rdr2 = cmd220.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr2.Read())
{
    TAT = rdr["TAT"].ToString();            
}

con220.Close();
MessageBox.Show(TAT);//ERROR: use of unassigned local variable TAT
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you stop writing raw ADO.NET code.  There's no reason to do so anymore with the myriad of excellent tools out there.  Consider something like Dapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string TAT = string.Empty; 
while (rdr2.Read())
{
     TAT = rdr["TAT"].ToString();
}

con220.Close();
MessageBox.Show(TAT);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Compiler has to verify that the local variable is assigned in all the paths that might execute. In your case the while block might not be executed if the reader returned empty results. So the compiler can't really verify the `TAT` is guaranteed to be assigned.

So you can do this before the while loop.

```
string TAT = null;
```